# Return type of a bi-dereferenced iterator

Tags: c++, stl, c++98, listiterator

During a test at university I faced this question regarding lists in the STL, C++ version 98:

> Given these lines: `list<A*> l; l.push_back(new A);` what is the
>   return type of the call `**(l.begin())`?

Among the available answers there was `A` and `A&` (the others are not relevant).

I supposed it to be *A*, but professor stated it's *A&*.

I learned that the dereference of an iterator returns a reference to the element of the list, so `*(l.begin())` should return an object whose type is `(A*)&`.
Then another dereference like `**(l.begin())` should *"go through"* the reference given by the list container and even through the pointer to A and eventually return an object of `A` type.

What is the correct interpretation? Please provide an explanation.

Comment: `A` is very different from `A&`, there is no room for interpretation and you could simply try it out

Comment: @tobi303 I know the difference between a variable and a reference to a variable. Please read my question again. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If `p` is of type `A*`, then `*p` is of type `A&`.

If `p` is of type `A*&` (reference to a pointer), then `*p` is also of type `A&`.

If `x` is of `type list<T>::iterator`, then `*x` is of type `T&`, and if `T==A*`, then `**x` is of type `A&`.

Comment: Thanks for editing, Nathan. I wasn't aware of this capability. Is there some documentation of this markdown/markup thing?

Comment: There's a "?" icon to the far right of the editing toolbar, above the edition area.

Comment: Ok. I see a "help" button. Thanks for drawing my attention to this!

Comment: @AdiLevin From what I learned about C, and since C and C++ should not have any difference in the management of pointers, when you dereference a pointer you get a *value*, and *not* a reference to a value. So if `p` is of type `A*`, then `*p` is of type `A`.<br>Please provide some sources to state the different behavior in C++.

Answer (score 0):

In [section 5.3.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) you can find

> The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it
>   is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the result is an **lvalue** referring to the object or
>   function to which the expression points. If the type of the expression
>   is “pointer to `T`,” the type of the result is “`T`.”

Comment: completely useless and not linked to my question.

Comment: @bebo Sorry for useless of my post. I found your question interesting and I try to find in c++ reference manual an explanation of what your professor said.

Comment: Thank you for your effort anyway. I consider your answer useless because it doesn't reply to my doubt, since it's only a quotation from the manual. If you expose what are your thoughts about my question and link some sources I could accept your answer.